How Centrality Measures Can be Accounted for in a Multigraph
Given the following edges for a DIRECTED multigraph, it seems that Mathematica only counts multiple edges to or from a node once. I have the following network and need to account for the multiple edges (and their directions) into the basic centrality measures shown. Any advice is most welcomed!
ClearAll;
edges = {S1 -> F1, S1 -> F1, S1 -> F1, S1 -> F1, S1 -> S2, S1 -> S2, 
   S1 -> S2, S1 -> S3, S1 -> S3, S3 -> S1, S3 -> S1, S3 -> S1, 
   S3 -> S1, S1 -> F3, S2 -> S1, S2 -> F5, S2 -> F6, S3 -> F4, 
   S3 -> S1, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3, S5 -> S3};
{VertexCount[edges], EdgeCount[edges], GraphHub[edges]}
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic, VertexSize -> 0.35, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 11, BaseStyle -> {Arrowheads -> 0.02}]

N[Mean[DegreeCentrality[edges]]]
DegreeCentrality[edges];
SortBy[{VertexList[edges], DegreeCentrality[edges]}\[Transpose], 
   N@*Last] // Reverse;
TableForm[%]
BetweennessCentrality[edges];
SortBy[{VertexList[edges], BetweennessCentrality[edges]}\[Transpose], 
   N@*Last] // Reverse;
TableForm[%]
EdgeBetweennessCentrality[edges];
SortBy[{EdgeList[edges], 
     EdgeBetweennessCentrality[edges]}\[Transpose], N@*Last] // 
  Reverse;
TableForm[%]


The question is too general if you just say "centrality measures", without specifying which. Don't expect the behaviour to be the same for all. If you ask about a set of specific centrality measures, we can discuss whether those make sense for multigraphs (not everything does), what specific definition makes sense, whether Mathematica follows that definition, and what alternatives are there. The short answer is that IGraph/M has very good support for multigraphs.

I'm interested in Degree Centrality, Betweenness Centrality, and EdgeBetweennessCentrality. Also, VertexDegree and VertexDegree In/Out. I would love to learn more about how to apply IGraph/M and would appreciate how it would apply here. Thank u ... 42700

You can use the centrality functions of IGraph/M in exactly the same way as you use the built-in ones. Most IGraph/M centrality functions do support both edge weights and multi-edges, even when the built-in alternatives don't.
